# Placing mines on a 2d list to random spots

Tags: python, list, random

I have to add mines (in this case 35 mines) on to a 2d list(field). The field is created like this.

```
field = []
for row in range(10):
   field.append([])
   for col in range(15):
      field[-1].append(" ")
```

I also have a list of tuples that represent free squares where mines can be placed.

```
free = []
for x in range(15):
   for y in range(10):
      free.append((x, y))
```

What I thought of doing was getting a random sample from the free squares with random.sample(free, 35)
but I don't know how to place mines into the field according to the random sample I have gotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea:

```
mines = random.sample(free, 35)
```

Now `mines` is a list of `(x, y)` pairs. All you need to do is iterate over this list and set the mine at the coordinates in the field. If you built `field` correctly, it is a 2D list of strings. You just need to set the string at `(x, y)` to a symbol that represents a mine.